# my calendar app is jumping some months when i switch to the next month

Tags: javascript, calendar

Hey there guys am new at javascript and jquery but for a project i needed to create a web based calendar which displays the current month, enables switching of months and displaying the proper day of the month, my problem is that i keep getting an error which i cant understand, i have tried changing the code several times but nothing works...please assist p.s my current feature enables switching for the current year only any assistance with switching to to next year after this one i.e from december 2016 to january 2017 or prev year i.e from january 2016 to december 2015 is appreciated here is my code

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script type='text/javascript' src='/my project2/assets/javascript/jquery/jquery.js'></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            #calendar-container{
            padding:10px;
            width:832px;
            height:415px;
            text-align:center;
            border-radius:3px;
            border:1px solid #e1e1e1;
            font-size:16px;
            font-family:arial;
            min-width:832px;
            }
            #prev{
            float:left;
            }
            #next{
            float:right;
            }
            #calendar-container>div{
            padding:0;
            margin-bottom:10px; 
            }
            #calendar-month-year{
            margin:5px;
            }
            #calendar-dates > table > tr > td{
            padding:20px;
            border:1px solid #e1e1e1;               
            }
            #events{
            font-size: 14px;
            position: relative;
            top: -14px;
            left: -15px;
            border-radius:5px;  
            color:#00868b;  
            font-size:15px;         
            }
            a{
            padding:20px;
            text-decoration:none;
            }
            table{
            border:1px solid #eee;
            width:832px;
            }
            #today{
            background-color: red;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 30px;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){          
                var d=new Date();
                var month=d.getMonth();
                var year=d.getFullYear(); //2014
                var daysinMonth=daysInMonth(month, year);
                var calendar="";
                $("#calendar").click(function(){
                    $("#calendar-container").addClass("active");
                    $("#calendar").html("close calendar");
                    calendarGenerator();
                });
                $("#prev").click(function(prevMonth){
                    prevMonth=month-1;
                    $("table").remove();
                    calendarGenerator(prevMonth);
                });
                $("#next").click(function(nextMonth){
                    nextMonth=month+1;
                    $("table").remove();
                    calendarGenerator(nextMonth);
                });

            function daysInMonth(month, year){
                //added the one so it would pick february, apparently here 1-jan 2-feb not 0-jan and 1-feb
                return new Date(year, month+1, 0).getDate();
            }
            function calendarGenerator(nextMonth){    
                var monthName=["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
                var today=d.getDate();
                daysToEndMonth=daysinMonth-today;
                if(nextMonth==null){
                    month=month; //0-11
                }else{
                    month=nextMonth;
                }
                var firstDate=monthName[month]+" "+1+" "+year;//September 1 2014
                var tmp=new Date(firstDate).toDateString();//Mon Sep 01 2014...
                var firstDay=tmp.substring(0, 3); //Mon
                var dayName=["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
                var dayNo=dayName.indexOf(firstDay);//1
                var days=new Date(year, month+1, 0).getDate();//30 //Tue Sep 30 2014... 
                var calendar=getCalendar(dayNo, days, today);
                document.getElementById("calendar-month-year").innerHTML=monthName[month]+" "+year; 
                document.getElementById("calendar-dates").appendChild(calendar);                
            }
            //document.getElementById("calendar-dates").innerHTML=calendar;
            function getCalendar(dayNo, days, today){
                var table=document.createElement("table");
                var tr=document.createElement("tr");
                //row for the day letters
                for(var c=0; c<=6; c++){
                    var td=document.createElement("td");
                    td.innerHTML='SMTWTFS'[c];
                    tr.appendChild(td);
                }
                table.appendChild(tr);
                //create 2nd row
                tr=document.createElement("tr");
                var c;
                for(c=0; c<=6; c++){
                    if(c==dayNo){
                        break;
                    }
                var td=document.createElement("td");
                td.innerHTML="";
                tr.appendChild(td);
                }
                var count=1;
                for(; c<=6; c++){
                    var td=document.createElement("td");
                    td.innerHTML="<a href='#' class='days'><span id='events'>"+6+"</span>"+count+"</a>";
                    count++;
                    if(count==today+1){
                        td.innerHTML="<a href='#' id='today' class='days' style=''><span id='events'></span>"+(count-1)+"</a>";
                    }
                    tr.appendChild(td); 
                }
                table.appendChild(tr);
                //rest of the daterows
                for(var r=3; r<=6; r++){
                    tr=document.createElement("tr");
                    for(var c=0; c<=6; c++){
                        if(count>days){
                        table.appendChild(tr);
                        return table
                    }
                    if(count==today+1){
                        td.innerHTML="<a href='#' id='today' class='days'><span id='events'></span>"+(count-1)+"</a>";
                    }
                    var td=document.createElement("td");
                    td.innerHTML="<a href='#' class='days'><span id='events'>"+14+"</span>"+count+"</a>";
                    count++;
                    tr.appendChild(td);
                    }
                    table.appendChild(tr);
                }
            }
    });

            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id='calendar'>open calendar</button><br/>
        <div id="calendar-container" class="inactive">
            <div id="calendar-header">
                <span id="calendar-month-year"></span>
                <button id="prev">prev</button>
                <button id="next">next</button>
            </div>
            <span id="calendar-dates"></span>
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Describe the exact issue, set up a fiddle and post just the relevant code please

Comment: okay guys here is the updated version of the fiddle which actually works [myfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/churchill/0Lg1ujst/)